# How do I open a file browser in the Netbook Edition?

Tags: 10.10, unity, nautilus

I can't figure out how to get a file browser (Nautilus, etc.) in  Netbook Edition 10.10 (Unity).  How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to open the trash bin at the bottom. That will open your file browser. After doing that you can right click the file browser icon on unity and select the option so it stays there now on. It did take me time to realize that was the workaround. Luck!

Comment: thats great took full two day to search for simple soln really ubuntu is so simple to operate

Comment: Thanks... it seems like you should at least be able to get to it by searching the applications, but neither "Nautilus" nor "File Browser" turns up anything

Comment: Well, for our friend SpashHit it took only one hour and some minutes to get the answer here.